# FIRDatabaseReference returns nil, UserID retrievable though

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to retrieve data from my Firebase database, but I'm stuck at the database reference returning nil. However, I successfully can retrieve the UserID, so I don't think it's not properly connected to my database:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabaseUI

class LoggedInViewController: UIViewController {

var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!
let userid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid

  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        UIDLabel.text = String((userid)!) // The Label shows the UID
        reflabel.text = String(ref)       // The Label shows "nil"
    }
}
```

My goal is to retrieve data from the path using this method:

```
   func getQuery() -> FIRDatabaseQuery {
        let myTopPostsQuery = (ref.child("user-posts")).child(getUid()))
        return myTopPostsQuery
    }
```

But obviously this doesn't work since I'm getting an error because of the *nil* reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `viewDidLoad` use `FIRDatabase.database().reference()`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    //....
}
```

Comment: @FelixF. mention not :)